# Find number of "false" from a datatable using linq C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `DataTable dt`

```
--------------------------------
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
--------------------------------
true | false|false|true |false
false| true |false|false|false
true | false|false|true |false
false| false|false|true |false
```

I want to use linq and fetch number of "false" in col1.

****Where false is string***

Comment: @Plutonix Even worse is that the duplicate question was by the same user. I have flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: I know that.  It isnt really a moderator issue.  Some one with a gold C# badge will see it and close it soon.  @krillgar

Comment: Hello @krillgar and plutonix this question is different as this time i have to use linq, also please read my last question it was very different from this one. Hope i have explained my question, if you find it not clear please do edit this.

Comment: The problem is that you're asking the exact same question, with one minor caveat. You got several good answers, but didn't acknowledge any of them. If a straight SQL answer isn't what you were looking for, then you should have edited your question faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this using linq:

```
int count = from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(r => r.Field<string>("col1") == "false")
  .Count();
```

Or also:

```
int count = from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
  .Count(r => r.Field<string>("col1") == "false");
```

Comment: Thanks @octavioccI

Comment: you're welcome my friend, glad I could help ;)

Comment: i am getting null pointer exception in case one column is empty, i mean there is no value. How to put null check?

Comment: Well, that's going to depend how you want to interpret `null` values, if you want to exclude them, then you can change your condition to something like this:  `(r.Field<string>("col1")?? "true") == "false"`, otherwise, change "true" string to "false"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int count = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Count(r => !bool.Parse(r["col1"] as string));
```

If you dont want to parse the strings:

```
int count = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Count(r => r["col1"] == "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
int count = dt.AsEnumerable().Count(c => c["col1"].ToString() == "false");
```

make sure you're using [DataRowExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
var count = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row.Field<bool>("col1"))         
    .Count(c => !c);
```

or (if column type is string)

```
var count = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row.Field<string>("col1"))           
    .Count(c => c == "false");
```

Working [`Code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FKUr0v)